# Compare two files and combine different columns of two files together into a single file using shell

Tags: shell

I have two files file1.txt and file2.txt.

file1.txt

```
Amal=123=amal@gmail.com
Anil=342=anil@gmail.com
Ajith=548=ajith@gmail.com
Aravind=998=arav@gmail.com
```

file2.txt

```
Anil=Active
Amal=Active
Ajith=Inactive
Aravind=Active
Midhun=Active
```

I need to add an extra column in file1.txt from file2.txt mentioning whether each of them is active or inactive and also remove lines from file2.txt which are not present in file1.txt.(for example, Midhun is not present in file1.txt. So i need to remove midhun from file2.txt)

My output file should be

output.txt

```
Amal=123=Active
Anil=342=Active
Ajith=548=Inactive
Aravind=998=Active
```

I tried the following. But it is not working.

```
while IFS= read -r line    
do
    key=`echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $1}'` < file1.txt
    key2=`echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'` < file1.txt
    value=`echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'` < file2.txt
    echo "$key=$key2=$value"
done
```

Comment: Please do apply CODE TAGS to you samples and CODES in your question and let us know then, as this is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

No need for scripting. Sort the files and then it's a simple join.

```
join -t= <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

---

To comply with the OP's update, let's *cut* only the first two fields of file1:

```
join -t= <(sort file1.txt | cut -d= -f-2) <(sort file2.txt)
```

Comment: Hello Pacholik, Thanks for the reply. But the command is not working.

Comment: @AjinJoy "is not working" is very vague. How is it "not working"? What does that mean? Does it output wrong output? Does the command exit with nonzero exit status? What happens? What does not happen? [For the input you provided, it outputs almost the same what you specified, repl link](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/MonstrousTalkativeCensorware), only lines are in different order.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Since OP changed his requirement so adding this solution now.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="="
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
($1 in a){
  $3=""
  sub(/=$/,"")
  print $0,a[$1]
}
'  Input_file2   Input_file1
```

---

---

This should be a simple task for `awk`, please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a){print $0,a[$1]}' file2 file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code here.

```
awk '              ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{             ##Starting BEGIN section for this program from here.
  FS=OFS="="       ##Setting FS and OFS value as = here for all lines.
}                  ##Closing BLOCK for BEGIN here.
FNR==NR{           ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file is being read.
  a[$1]=$2         ##Creating array a with index $1 and value $2.
  next             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in a){         ##Checking condition ig $1 of current line(from file1) is present in array a then do following.
  print $0,a[$1]   ##Printing current line and value of array a with index $1 of current line here.
}
' file2 file1      ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Hello RavinderSingh, Thanks for the reply. I tried this command also. Still not getting. When I execute your command it is not even printing anything.

Comment: @AjinJoy, Are you passing both of the files to it? Also are you files having same data as shown samples? Because for me this command worked well for shown samples, lemme know on my questions.

Comment: Hii RavindherSingh, Iam passing both the files. And having same data as shown in samples.
Can you give me an output like this
Amal=123=Active
Anil=342=Active
Ajith=548=Inactive
Aravind=998=Active

Comment: Remove that mail id from output.txt. Just print "name=number=Status(Active/Inactive)"

Comment: @AjinJoy, Sorry but its not clear, is output is not same like you shown in your question? please do lemme know on same, in comments it is NOT clear.

Comment: Hello RavinderSingh, If you check my output.txt file, you can see name, numbers,mail id and status(active or inactive) ie.,[Amal=123=amal@gmail.com=active]. Just remove that mail id from output.txt and print rest of the things.

Comment: I have made changes in my output.txt file. Can u check now. Sorry for the confusion. Iam new to shell script

Comment: @AjinJoy, Please check my EDIT solution and lemme know then?

Comment: Hello RavinderSingh, Still not working. It is not even printing anything. No error too

Comment: @AjinJoy For the content of files you specified the `awk` command outputs the output you specified in your question. Are you sure you are testing the command on correct files? How are you testing it?